# Get SRC from div contents

Tags: php, css, html, simple-html-dom

I have code that gets a div contents:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html("link");
$ret = $html->find('div'); 

echo $ret[0];

preg_match_all('/(src)=("[^"]*")/i',$ret[0], $link);

echo $link[0];
```

It returns the full div contents including all the CSS. However I just wanted it to echo the information after `src=` basically just echoing the image link and nothing else. I've tried to use preg_match with no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your HTML parser will help you there - there should be a `src` property in the `$ret` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [HTML parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) will help you there - there should be a `src` property in the `$ret` object:

```
echo $ret[0]->src;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regexp for that since you already use a dom parser.

```
foreach($ret as $element) 
       echo $element->src,'<br/>';
```